# Why can't I use first in informix subqueries

Tags: sql, informix

Why can't I use select first in subquery? Here I have some pseudo select which throws exception: `Cannot use 'first', 'limit' or 'skip' in this context.`

I don't understand why. I want to select first 10 IDs and then in other table rows which in this set

```
select * from Table1 where ID in ( select  first 10  ID from Table2)
```

How should I rewrite this select?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not very pretty but seems to work:

```
SELECT * FROM _tmp_table 
WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT id FROM 
      (SELECT FIRST 10 id FROM _tmp_table)
   )
```

Comment: hm ok this solve the problem but why there is such limitation in informx db ?

Comment: It's funny `select (select first 1 from sysmaster:sysdual) from sysmaster:sysdual` is not allowed, but `select (select x from ( select first 1 x from sysmaster:sysdual) ) from sysmaster:sysdual` is allowed. It's basically the same context.

Answer (score 6):

Because it's design this way...
I believe the IBM Informix engineers have some technical limitation for that, because is a old feature request from lot of Informix users... (despite there is no RFE about this at [IBM RFE](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/) site)

If you check the [Informix Manuals you will found the answer quoted here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_074.htm?lang=en):

> The Projection clause cannot include the SKIP, FIRST, or LIMIT
>   keywords in these contexts:
>
> - when the SELECT statement is part of a view definition
> - in a subquery, except in the FROM clause of the outer query
> - in a cross-server distributed query in which a participating database server does not support the SKIP, FIRST, or LIMIT keywords.

Just like @Michael answer, just a clear example how works... 
This in version 11.70 .

```
$ dbaccess -e sysmaster x.sql

Database selected.


select first 10 tabname[1,20] from systables
;

tabname

systables
syscolumns
sysindices
systabauth
syscolauth
sysviews
sysusers
sysdepend
syssynonyms
syssyntable

10 row(s) retrieved.


select t.tabname[1,20] from (select first 2 * from systables) as  t


tabname

systables
syscolumns

2 row(s) retrieved.


Database closed.
```